# node.js event not listening after connection

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a code where, socket is connected to node server.

```
io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket){
// socket object is printed with full of data.
// console.log works
// emit here works
});
```

but this emit is not received by client.

please help..
as well as, when i emit something from client side it is not recieved.

On the console, I can see whatever i emit in the server. but not getting listened on client side.

Client side code

```
 var socket = io.connect("http:///iag-stg.codewalla.com:8181");
 socket.on('same-event-name-as-in-server', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

Starting server as -

```
var express = require('express')
, app =  express()
, http = require('http')
, server = http.createServer(app)
, sio =  require('socket.io')
, io = sio.listen(server) 
, events = require('events')
, redis = require('redis')
, config = require('./Config');

server.listen(8181);
```

running the node using following command

```
node filename.js
```

When i connect to client, this is on console.

```
debug - served static content /socket.io.js
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized D4sz1PZoBhWgq-hzp8se
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/D4sz1PZoBhWgq-hzp8se
debug - set heartbeat interval for client D4sz1PZoBhWgq-hzp8se
debug - client authorized for
debug - websocket writing 1::
```

Comment: Change the name of the socket parameter:

Comment: @lyxio : thanks for your quick reply, but I have modified above question.please look at it..it is io.sockets.on("...")...

Comment: Ok, how are you creating the socket server?

Comment: @lyxio
appended the code used for starting socket server.

Comment: Just to be sure you are doing `console.log(data);` on browser, so you are checking the console on your browser right. Or you can add `alert(data);` in the client code to know you received anything.

Comment: @user568109 : for client I am checking web console in browser and for server I am looking at terminal. I am running same instance of node on port 8080 , will that affect in any way ?

Comment: No, it should not affect it. But do check if you are using 8080 on browser as well. In the example you gave you are using 8181.

Comment: no no ,this is another instance of the node which is running on 8181 and i want to connect to 8181 only.
Previous instance is running on 8080 already and client can connect to it without any failure like this..everything is ok on 8080.